# How do I handle the types for both paginated and non-paginated fetch results in the same function?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a fetch query that queries a backend API that can return paginated or non-paginated data.

The paginated data will come back as an object with meta and data sub-objects.

Non-paginated data just comes back as an array.

I can set the type for the non-paginated data as an array. How do I handle the case when paginated data comes back?

I want to do something like set a paginated interface then state that the result can be a workflow[] OR paginatedWorkflow

But my IDE says the paginated 'data' does not exist.

Code below:

```
interface paginatedWorkflow {
  meta: {};
  data: Workflow[]; 
}

export function useGetWorkflows(
 paginate: boolean,
 search: string,
 sort: string,
 order: string,
 page: number,
 size: number
) {
 return useFetch<Workflow[] | paginatedWorkflow>(uri, {
 method: "GET",
 baseURL: runtimeConfig.public.apiBaseURL,
 headers: {
 "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
 params: {
 paginate: paginate,
 search: search,
 sort: sort,
 order: order,
 page: page,
 size: size,
    },
  });
}
```

I call the function from within component or Pinia store, i.e.:

```
async getWorkflows(
      paginate: boolean,
      search: string,
      sort: string,
      order: string,
      page: number,
      size: number
    ) {
      const { data , pending, refresh, error } =
        await useGetWorkflows(
          paginate,
          search,
          sort,
          order,
          page,
          size
        );
      if (paginate) {
        this.workflows = data?.value?.data;
      } else {
        this.workflows = data?.value?? [];
      }
      if (error.value) {
        useNegativeNotify("Error retrieving workflows: " + error.value);
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a new type/interface called `PaginatedWorkflow` with two properties: `meta` (metadata) and `data` (an array of workflows).

Create a union type called `FetchResult` that can represent either an array of workflows or a paginated workflow object.
Modify the `useGetWorkflows` function to use the `FetchResult` type as the generic type argument for the `useFetch` function.
Update the function signature to include the required parameters for the fetch query.

Make sure to provide the appropriate values for the `uri`, `runtimeConfig.public.apiBaseURL`, and other necessary properties within the useFetch call.
With these changes, the `useGetWorkflows` function can handle both paginated and non-paginated fetch responses by specifying the `FetchResult` type.

Below is the your code that I modified, hope it helps

```
interface PaginatedWorkflow {
  meta: {};
  data: Workflow[]; 
}

type FetchResult = Workflow[] | PaginatedWorkflow;

export function useGetWorkflows(
  paginate: boolean,
  search: string,
  sort: string,
  order: string,
  page: number,
  size: number
) {
  return useFetch<FetchResult>(uri, {
    method: "GET",
    baseURL: runtimeConfig.public.apiBaseURL,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    params: {
      paginate: paginate,
      search: search,
      sort: sort,
      order: order,
      page: page,
      size: size,
    },
  });
}
```

I hope this works for you

```
async getWorkflows(
  paginate: boolean,
  search: string,
  sort: string,
  order: string,
  page: number,
  size: number
) {
  const { data, pending, refresh, error } = await useGetWorkflows(
    paginate,
    search,
    sort,
    order,
    page,
    size
  );

  if (paginate) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      this.workflows = data;
    } else {
      this.workflows = data?.data ?? [];
    }
  } else {
    this.workflows = data ?? [];
  }

  if (error) {
    useNegativeNotify("Error retrieving workflows: " + error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you help with calling the function? I've added code to my question. How do I avoid the typescript errors complaining data.value.data does not exist on FetchResult?

Comment: in order to be able to avoid TypeScript errors when accessing data.value.data on FetchResult, you can perform type checks and use conditional logic to handle both paginated and non-paginated responses appropriately.  I have edited my first response to include the conditional logic.